# Trouble targeting ul and li elements for drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have this menu coded and I have tried other methods as well, but it seems to me that I'm having trouble targeting the second ul list and il elements to display for the drop down menu, can anyone see the problem with this code?

Thank you so much!

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Artists</li>
              <ul>
                <li>Kasi</li>
                <li>Sin</li>
                <li>WORDUP</li>
              </ul>
            <li>Videos</li>
            <li>Store</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>

CSS:

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;

}

#nav {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #FFF;
}

#nav_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
  color: #FFDF00
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

#nav ul ul{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `ul`'s need to be in an `li`. Only an `li` can be a direct child of `ul`.

Then use CSS to hide the nested `ul`'s by default, then when you hover an `li`, display any nested `ul` that is a direct child.

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Artists
    <ul>
      <li>Kasi</li>
      <li>Sin</li>
      <li>WORDUP</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>Store</li>
</ul>
```